# it is possible to change the hardware brightness/contrast settings from software?

Tags: display

is it possible to change the hardware brightness and contrast settings from software? I know a few like F.lux  can apply filters, but sometimes those filters can cause graphical problems with some applications and are also often distracting,as well as not giving the amount of control as the button-press ones. 
I was asking as it was getting tiresome to adjust the brightness every few minutes(low is good for webpages, but pictures are hard to see,for example) and I'd like to have a way to add presets to do it faster.

Comment: Yes. It's just driver manipulation but it can be device specific.

Comment: Yes. Check out [PowerStrip](http://entechtaiwan.com/util/ps.shtm).